# Make sense of what you see

Tags: pattern

*Make sense* of what you see below. Replace the question marks.

---

### **? E ? T ? R ? E ? U ? N ? E**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This question appears to be missing the [letter-sequence](/questions/tagged/letter-sequence) tag, but let's assume that it *is* indeed a letter sequence, and we are therefore supposed to work out which letters are missing from the letter sequence...

...

This probably does the job:

> **L** E **T** T **E** R **S** E **Q** U **E** N **C** E (!)

Comment: Nice! man, you are quick on the draw for these aren't ya?

Comment: Maybe your tag should be a spoiler? ;)

Comment: @noedne *Or*, maybe the tag should be edited into the puzzle? ;)

Comment: @coffin_queen Haha, just lucky to log on to the site mere seconds after this one was posted and for something to just *click* :)